# Create React App and JEST property matchers

Tags: jestjs, create-react-app

I've got this component that I've simplified for this example as part of a bigger create react app

```
import React from 'react';

function myVersion() {
  return (
      <p className={'ActivateSound--para'} data-testid={`version`}>
          Version {process.env.REACT_APP_VERSION} has loaded, congrats!
      </p>
  );
}

export { myVersion };
```

and in the env I get the version from package.json

```
REACT_APP_VERSION=$npm_package_version
```

but in the test I've got

```
import React from 'react';
import { myVersion } from '../components/my-version';
import { render, screen, cleanup, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';

afterEach(cleanup);

describe('my version component', () => {
  test('snapshot hasnt changed', () => {
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
});
```

I am now looking at https://jestjs.io/docs/snapshot-testing#property-matchers. It seems I can exclude the version number somehow, I've tried a bunch of attempts but it's not ignoring the version number

```
    expect(container.firstChild).toMatchSnapshot({
      screen.getByTestId('version'): expect.any(String)
    });
```

Comment: Why not override the value for the test?

Comment: any examples of how to best override it?